# Find id from NVD3 Pie Chart

Tags: d3.js, meteor, nvd3.js

I looking for solution solve my problem. It reference sample from NVD3.ORG http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav

I try to find _id when I click one "Delete" button. I wrote this code and tested it but not working. Anyone can help please.

```
'click #delValues': function(){
        var name = $("#modifyChartName").val();
        var findId = function (name){
            Pie.findOne({label: name});
            return _id;
        };
        Pie.remove({
            _id: findId()
        });
        $("#modifyChartName").val("");
        $("#modifyChartValue").val("");
    }
```

Actually I really need to chick on Pie Chart and then get _id and hit "Delete" Button for Deleting.

```
    nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .showLabels(true);

    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(chart);

  return chart;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I was trying to do something similar and came up with a solution that might help in this case. I wanted to trigger highlighting of a certain row in a `<table>` (generated separately from the pie chart) when a corresponding slice of the pie chart was hovered. I was able to do this by getting the `pointIndex` from `tooltipContent` (which I had been using to customize what appears in the tooltip.

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
            .tooltipContent( function (key, y, e, graph) {
                // Get an index number of the hovered slice
                var sliceId = e.pointIndex;
                // Do something with that id (separate from nvd3)
                $("#completionRate tbody tr:nth-child("+sliceId+")").addClass("info");
                // Customize the actual tooltip
                return y.substring(0,y.indexOf(".")) + " Patients<br/>" + key;
            });
```

I can imagine using the same technique to get an id/index which you could then use to assign to a delete function.